# Saving multiple files

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUploadMultiple(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine("C://Reports//36000", fileName);

                file.SaveAs(path);

            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I have 2 files that I am testing on - as such it should loop twice. The first saves fine to the given path. When the code goes and tries to do the second file, I get the following message:

*The process cannot access the file 'C:\Reports\36000\Report #36028.pdf' because it is being used by another process.*

I think I need to do a dispose but, when I tried to do `file.Dispose()` this didn't appear to be correct in `Intellisense`.

Comment: seems to me like both files have the same Name and SaveAs cannot override the existing file. So maybe System.IO.File.Exist(path) helps here or make sure the filename is unique

Comment: I do need to overrride the file though in case they want to update the file.

Comment: Note that the user may want to override the same file with the same name.

Comment: How do you know which of your files is the "original" and which is the "updated" version? An enumerable does not have a specific order and you have no more information than the files themselves. Apart from this: Why would a user upload two files if one of them is going to be overwritten instantly when it is uploaded?

Comment: @fero - What I meant was that the file may exist on the system and the user may upload a file with the same name to override it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to delete an existing File, before saving:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
 System.IO.File.Delete(path);
file.SaveAs(path);
```